# CSS: Print font colors in Firefox

Tags: css, printing, fonts, colors

I'm trying to style a web page for printing. I want fonts to be printed in the original color. In Firefox fonts are always turn to black when printing. The setting of "Print Background (colors & images)" is turned on.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you give some code or images for example?

Answer (score 1):

I had success with the solution similar in Firefox 70.0.1 to that described by Plenarto.
However I needed to set the color to transparent for Firefox to print the text as white.

```
h1 {
    color: transparent;
    text-shadow: 0 0 0px #fff;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code in css on element which you want print. In your case, this is font.

```
-webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
color-adjust: exact;
```

`-webkit-print-color-adjust` have two values:

- `economy` (default) allows the printer to use its default ink-saving
  mode.
- `exact` hints that the printer should preserve the colors.

Comment: this doesn't help in FF

Answer (score 0):

I have found such solution:

```
@media print {
      h1 /* or anything else you want to style */ {
        color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
        text-shadow: 0 0 0 #ccc;
      }

      @media print and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
        h1 /* or anything else you want to style */ {
          color: #ccc;
          -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
        }
      }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried changing color values in the code above to other then black?

Comment: Yep. (15 characters in comments...)